# Swift - How to call Selector() on method with arguments?

Tags: ios, function, swift, selector

I'm learning Swift and need to call my method on tap, here is the code:

```
var gestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer()
myView.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
gestureRecognizer.addTarget(self, action: Selector(dismiss(nil)))
```

This returns error - `Could not find an overload for init that accepts the supplied arguments`

I also tried like `Selector("dismiss:nil")` and `Selector("dismiss(nil)")` with no luck..

Here the method I'm calling:

```
func dismiss(completion: (() -> Void)!) {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: completion)
}
```

Comment: The answer you reference does not answer this question, which is asking how to pass arguments to a function.  dismiss() vs dismiss(theParameter :String) for instance.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just use the name of the method as a string:

```
gestureRecognizer.addTarget(self, action: "dismiss:")
```

Edit: In Swift 3.0 you will have to use the following syntax:

```
gestureRecognizer.addTarget(self, action: #selector(dismiss(_:)))
```

Answer (score 8):

You don't pass arguments in selectors. You only represent that there is one with a colon. Additionally, you don't have to use the Selector type at all. If you pass in a String literal, it is converted to a Selector for you.

```
gestureRecognizer.addTarget(self, action:"dismiss:")
```

Comment: Then where do you pass the arguments?